# Почему в имплементации не указано, что методы deprecated (хотя в документации это так)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences

Для того, чтоб использовать `EncryptedSharedPreferences` я добавил вот такую зависимость

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"
```

И пользуюсь вот так

```
...
        val sharedPref = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
            PREF_NAME,
            MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC),
            context,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        )
...
```

потом я наткнулся на офф док - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/MasterKeys где говориться, что этот класс `deprecated` и здесь есть несколько предложений о том как это можно сделать правильно - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504831/5098477

НО, почему когда я в коде открываю имплементацию класса или метода негде нет упоминания о том, что это `deprecated`?

```
/**
 * Convenient methods to create and obtain master keys in Android Keystore.
 *
 * <p>The master keys are used to encrypt data encryption keys for encrypting files and preferences.
 */
public final class MasterKeys {
    private MasterKeys() {
    }
```

или тут

```
    /**
     * Creates or gets the master key provided
     *
     * The encryption scheme is required fields to ensure that the type of
     * encryption used is clear to developers.
     *
     * @param keyGenParameterSpec The key encryption scheme
     * @return The key alias for the master key
     */
    @NonNull
    public static String getOrCreate(
            @NonNull KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        validate(keyGenParameterSpec);
        if (!MasterKeys.keyExists(keyGenParameterSpec.getKeystoreAlias())) {
            generateKey(keyGenParameterSpec);
        }
        return keyGenParameterSpec.getKeystoreAlias();
    }
```

Не пойму почему не показано, что эти методы `deprecated`?

Comment: Документация по какой-то причине отражает версию библиотеки, которая еще не была выпущена. В версии 1.0.0 этот класс не был помечен как Deprecated, но стоит ожидать что это произойдет в будущих стабильных версиях библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подключаете версию библиотеки **1.0.0**, на тот момент класс `MasterKeys` не был помечен как Deprecated и не существовало класса `MasterKey.Builder` (который предлагается использовать вместо `MasterKeys`).

В [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#security-crypto-1.1.0-alpha01) можно увидеть, что класс `MasterKeys` был помечен как Deprecated с версии **1.1.0-alpha01**.

Вы можете попробовать использовать нестабильную версию **1.1.0-alpha01**, либо дождаться выхода **1.1.0**, чтобы иметь возможность использовать новый класс `MasterKey.Builder` вместо `MasterKeys`.